# How to get a point cloud from kinect

Tags: kinect, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an easy way to get a segmented point cloud from the kinect based on one color?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11633/how-to-get-a-point-cloud-from-kinect/) by [toniOliver](https://answers.ros.org/users/1236/tonioliver/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2011-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use a [Passthrough Filter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros/Filters#PassThrough) to exclude points not within a specified range for any of the fields in your pointcloud (including R,G, and B).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1